# Make flutter web Image widgets clickable

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can I download an image from flutter web?

The image is not clickable/dragable and shows no context menu on right click, for example to "save as".
Web implementation  - http://watools.xyz/ankush_apis/flutter_projects/youtube/#/

Is there an alternative Image widget, to make it *web clickable*?
Like [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) and [SelectableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html).
Maybe an Property, a pub package?
Any answers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget? It supports gesture and already implements the clickable effect.

```
     InkWell(
          child: Image.network(
              'https://i.picsum.photos/id/9/250/250.jpg?hmac=tqDH5wEWHDN76mBIWEPzg1in6egMl49qZeguSaH9_VI'),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Options'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: Text('Save image'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Code for download the image
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: This is NOT an adequate answer. You are forced to provide your own implementation rather than the default behavior that browsers provide, which limits your actions considerably. I want to be able to get the link of the image that is hosted. How will I retrieve that using this method?